# ChildFragment Ошибка

Tags: android, android-studio

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Решил сделать `ChildFragment` но выкидывает исключение, не понимаю чего от меня хотят.

**ParentFragment**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ConstraintLayout v =(ConstraintLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_farm,container,false);
        //
        Fragment child=new BaffList();
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.bottom_sheet,child,"baffList").commitNow();
        return v;
    }
```

**ChildFragment**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.sheet_baff,container);
        return v;
    }
```

**Разметка ParentFragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   //

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/baffList"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtPlusSecond"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        tools:context=".Activities.Main.Core">

        <include layout="@layout/fragment_bafflist" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment_bafflist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

</LinearLayout>
```

**sheet_baff**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPurple"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="топ"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="контент"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.sheet_baff,container);
```

**Заменил на**

```
View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.sheet_baff,container,false);
```